# TestParent<T>.Sub.eventHandler is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

`My environment: Unity 5.1.3-f1 on MacOS X 10.8.5`

I have some problem with the following code.

```
using UnityEngine;

class TestParent<T>
{
    void doTest()
    {
        var item = new Sub();

        item.eventHandler += (obj) => Debug.Log(obj);
    }

    class Sub
    {
        public event System.Action<Object> eventHandler;
    }
}
```

Above code produces following error.

```
Assets/TestScript.cs(9,14): error CS0122: TestParent<T>.Sub.eventHandler is inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

The `eventHanlder` variable is defined with public.
However, it seems that the `eventHandler` is treated as private or so.

This error will disappear when the class is defined as follows without `<T>`:

```
class TestParent 
{
   ...
}
```

I would like to know the workaround for this.

Comment: print Sub(); class too..

Comment: So is all that code in `TestScript.cs`? That looks like it should work... it may well be a bug in the version of the Mono compiler that Unity is using :(

Comment: Maybe try make `Sub` class `public`

Comment: All the code is in TestScript.cs. I tried adding public to Sub, but it didn't work. And my colleague says that the code works with VisualStudio.